# ActionPerformed not working in custom component

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to write a code that creates a thing that I call gun and I want to be able to move it to the right or left. I implemented `KeyListener` and `ActionListener` methods, but `actionPerformed` is not working. However, `keyPressed` method does work. Any ideas what I missed?

```
public class Gun extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int GUN_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int GUN_HEIGHT = 30;
    private static final int GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT = 20;
    private static final int GUN_UPPER_WIDTH = GUN_WIDTH / 4;
    int x, y;
    int velX;

    public Gun() {
        x = 250 - GUN_WIDTH / 2;
        y = 500 - GUN_HEIGHT;
        velX = 0;
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int upperX = x + GUN_WIDTH / 2 - GUN_UPPER_WIDTH / 2;
        int upperY = y - GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, GUN_WIDTH, GUN_HEIGHT);
        g2d.fillRect(upperX, upperY, GUN_UPPER_WIDTH, GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void left() {
        velX = -1;
    }

    public void right() {
        velX = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
            System.out.println("LEFT");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x += velX;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gun gun = new Gun();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        gun.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        frame.add(gun);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: I see you used `addKeyListener(this)`, but did you do the same for `addActionListener` somewhere?

Comment: Consider using [`Key Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a `KeyListener`.

Comment: @Zircon I had an idea that it was something wrong with that. However, here comes another problem. When I try to put 'addActionListener(this)' in the constructor, I just can't because Eclipse does not let me to do so, it's acting like this method does not even exist. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

To get the actionPerformed method to run, you need to add an ActionListener for that object. Since you didn't add an actionListener, you will never run the actionPerformed method.

check Java tutorials on action listeners: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

For actionPerformed method to run, you need to add ActionListener in the corresponding object. But JPanel class does not have method called addActionListener.

Looking at your code it seems like you do not need to implement ActionListener interface. You can get rid of actionPerformed method then. All you have to do is copy the code inside the actionPerformed method and paste them inside the if conditions of keyPressed method. Below is the code that works as expected:

```
package edu.uno.ai.planning.bfs;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gun extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int GUN_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int GUN_HEIGHT = 30;
    private static final int GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT = 20;
    private static final int GUN_UPPER_WIDTH = GUN_WIDTH / 4;
    int x, y;
    int velX;

    public Gun() {
        x = 250 - GUN_WIDTH / 2;
        y = 500 - GUN_HEIGHT;
        velX = 0;
        addKeyListener(this);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int upperX = x + GUN_WIDTH / 2 - GUN_UPPER_WIDTH / 2;
        int upperY = y - GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, GUN_WIDTH, GUN_HEIGHT);
        g2d.fillRect(upperX, upperY, GUN_UPPER_WIDTH, GUN_UPPER_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void left() {
        velX = -1;
    }

    public void right() {
        velX = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
            System.out.println("LEFT");
            x += velX;
            repaint();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
            x += velX;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gun gun = new Gun();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        gun.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        frame.add(gun);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just did that! But isn't it a bad practice to use same piece of code a few times?

Comment: If the duplicated code was multiple lines or had to be used more than handful of times, then it is certainly a good idea to declare method and call that method. But in your case, the duplicated code was two lines and had to used only in two places. Thus, I just copied the lines to individual places. But you could always declare a separate method and call that method when needed. Programming is a combination of science and art. Whether to declare method, falls in art section and is somewhat subjective. Thus, use your best instinct to decide whether to use methods or duplicate the code.